# SQL Query to get calendar week with highest number of matching ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data in a table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTest;
SELECT calendar_week, id
INTO #tmpTest
FROM ( VALUES 
(201106, 635),
(201106, 636),
(201106, 642),
(201106, 643),
(201107, 635),
(201107, 636),
(201107, 642),
(201107, 643),
(201211, 635),
(201211, 636),
(201211, 642),
(201211, 643),
(201211, 4421),
(201901, 635),
(201901, 636),
(201901, 642),
(201902, 635),
(201902, 636),
(201902, 642),
(201902, 4421)) AS t_insert (calendar_week, id);
```

What I need to know are the calendar weeks with the most matching ids. None of the data is known beforehand. That is, calendar_week and id are random. So in this case, it would be 201106 and 201107, because they have identical ids and we have two calendar weeks. Any ideas, how to accomplish this? My head is empty. Thanks a lot.

Edit:
Maybe it's clearer if I describe it this way:

`Calendar week 201106 has these ids: 635, 636, 642, 643
Calendar week 201107 has these ids: 635, 636, 642, 643`

So the ids of these two calendar weeks are identical and I can count two weeks with these ids. All other calendar weeks are different and count only one. So 201106 and 201107 are the winners and the desired output is 201106, 201107.

Comment: Why is it not 4421 which is there for week 201902 and 201211?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is just `group by` with `order by`:

```
select top (1) with ties calendar_week, count(*)
from tmpTest
group by calendar_week
order by count(*) desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af66523cd3987e6c3fc0739223b5e8d8) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want only one row when there are ties, remove the `with ties`.

Comment: This returns just 1 row 201211 which is not correct

Comment: @Ralf intend to return 2 rows 201106 and 201107 because there ID's are same 635,636,642,643

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with concatenation. Not so beautiful, but it works.

```
SELECT calendar_week
FROM
(
    SELECT calendar_week,
           (
               SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), a.id) + ',' AS [text()]
               FROM #tmpTest a
               WHERE a.calendar_week = b.calendar_week
               FOR XML PATH('')
           ) AS ids_concatenated
    FROM #tmpTest b
    GROUP BY calendar_week
) t
WHERE ids_concatenated =
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           ids_concatenated
    FROM
    (
        SELECT calendar_week,
               (
               SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), a.id) + ',' AS [text()]
                   FROM #tmpTest a
                   WHERE a.calendar_week = b.calendar_week
                   FOR XML PATH('')
               ) AS ids_concatenated
        FROM #tmpTest b
        GROUP BY calendar_week
    ) t
    GROUP BY ids_concatenated
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
);
```